# Using statement in Cake

Tags: c#, roslyn, cakebuild

I am trying to use a `using` statement in Cake so that I can use the `Regex` class.

The line where I am trying to use this:

```
var matchesFromBranch = Regex.Matches(gitBranch, jiraPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Select(m => m.Value).Distinct();
```

This gave me the following error:

> .../build.cake(43,25): error CS0103: The name 'Regex' does not exist in the current context
>
> .../build.cake(43,63): error CS0103: The name 'RegexOptions' does not exist in the current context

So I added `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` to the top of my file. Now I get the following error:

> .../build.cake(43,25): error CS0433: The type 'Regex' exists in both 'System.Text.RegularExpressions, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>
> .../build.cake(43,63): error CS0433: The type 'RegexOptions' exists in both 'System.Text.RegularExpressions, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Comment: Could you put your `web.config` content?

Comment: What happens if you use the fully qualified name instead of the using? `var matchesFromBranch = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(gitBranch, jiraPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Select(m => m.Value).Distinct();`

Comment: @D-Shih I don't have a web.config. How is this related?

Comment: @Jonathan Chase: Was also my first guess but that gives me the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the **tools/Cake** folder and remove any references to the System.Text.RegularExpressions assembly and re run your bootstrapping script.

Even just delete the tools folder and re run the bootstrapper.

Comment: I removed the tools folder, did a `git clean -dfx` to be sure, but it still gave me those errors. Do I need the using statement or not?

Comment: Yes, you need the using statement for that namespace.